# Best way to copy a file from a public S3 bucket to a private S3 bucket

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I need to copy from a publicly accessible resource on an AWS S3 bucket to a private S3 bucket while knowing the private bucket configuration(such as secretkey, accesskey, etc) using nodeJS AWS SDK.

My thoughts are using `http.get` or `request` to get the content of the public object and then simply use regular `S3.upload()` function, but maybe there is a more efficient way.

Thanks

Comment: Take a look at the copyObject method (http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/S3.html#copyObject-property).

Comment: If I'm correct, this will trigger an authorization error because you can't put the credentials of the destination bucket

Comment: Check the following Stackoverflow question/answers https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30959251/how-to-copy-move-all-objects-in-amazon-s3-from-one-prefix-to-other-using-the-aws

Comment: @MichaelLumbroso a copy-object request is sent to the destination bucket, not the source. The destination pulls the content across, internal to S3. You use the destination credentials to send the request.

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot The copy object triggers authentication error because you will pass authentication credentials to the request and those credentials don't have access to the source bucket.

Comment: @ArpitSolanki the question refers to the source bucket as "public."

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot Yes. Even with a public bucket if you provide credentials it will throw an error because policies will be checked against those credentials and those credentials don't have access to that bucket. Only if you try it as anonymous user it will succeed