# How to copy the object from s3 to s3 using node.js

Tags: node.js, amazon-s3

I would like to know how to copy the object from s3 to s3 using node.js
With the aws s3 command, It could be executed as follows.

```
s3 cp --recursive s3://xx/yy  s3://zz/aa
```

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/S3.html#copyObject-property

I refer to above link,But I don't know how to do it using node.js

any Idea?

Comment: This might help - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30959251/how-to-copy-move-all-objects-in-amazon-s3-from-one-prefix-to-other-using-the-aws

Answer (score 36):

Note that `encodeURI` is required if the filename has special chars

```
    await S3.copyObject({
        Bucket: bucketName,
        CopySource: encodeURI(`/${sourceBucketName}/${filename}`),
        Key: filename,
    }).promise()
```

Comment: This is true and important! I just stumbled into this pitfall. I guess it's good practice to simply always `encodeURI` the CopySource. Otherwise, it might hit on you anytime. A german umlaut was enough to slam a `NetworkingError: Invalid character in header content ["x-amz-copy-source"]` at me.

Comment: That's incorrect. What should be used is `encodeURIComponent` as it encodes all the characters that AWS expects to be encoded. `encodeURI` would make it impossible to access file keys that contain e.g. `+` sign.

Answer (score 34):

If you just want to copy one object [copyObject](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/S3.html#copyObject-property) API.

```
 var params = {
  Bucket: "destinationbucket", 
  CopySource: "/sourcebucket/sourceKeyName", 
  Key: "targetKeyName"
 };
 s3.copyObject(params, function(err, data) {
   if (err) console.log(err, err.stack); // an error occurred
   else     console.log(data);           // successful response
 });
```

If you want to perform recursively for all objects in a bucket, then

1. List all the object keys in a bucket using the [listObjectsV2](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/S3.html#listObjectsV2-property) API.
2. If versioning is enabled in the *source-bucket* and you want to copy a specific version of the key, Invoke the [listObjectVersions](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/S3.html#listObjectVersions-property) API as well and get the *`Version-Id`* for each S3 Key.

   `NOTE: If versioning is not enabled, then you can ignore STEP-2.`
3. Call `copyObject` for each S3 Key and the `Version-Id` obtained in Step-1 and Step-2 respectively. `Version-id` is optional.

Comment: Just missing that copySource has to contain the bucket too. Thanks!

Answer (score 26):

If you want to really move (so not just copy, but in addition remove the source file)

```
const moveAndDeleteFile = async (file,inputfolder,targetfolder) => {
    const s3 = new AWS.S3();

    const copyparams = {
        Bucket : bucketname,
        CopySource : bucketname + "/" + inputfolder + "/" + file, 
        Key : targetfolder + "/" + file
    };

    await s3.copyObject(copyparams).promise();

    const deleteparams = {
        Bucket : bucketname,
        Key : inputfolder + "/" + file
    };

    await s3.deleteObject(deleteparams).promise();
    ....
}
```

Answer (score 8):

```js
s3.copyObject({
  Bucket,
  CopySource: `/${Bucket}/${Key}?versionId=${versionId}`,
  Key,
}).promise()
```

if you do pass a `versionId` this is what it looks like.

took me longer than i'd care to admit to figure out.

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
const headCode = await S3.headObject(params).promise();

if (headCode) {
  const res = await S3.copyObject({
    CopySource: sourceBucket + '/' + sourceKey,
    Bucket: destinationBucket,
    Key: destinationKey
  }).promise();
}
```