# Unable to copyobject using aws sdk node js

Tags: node.js, amazon-s3, aws-sdk-nodejs

I am using below code to copy object in aws bucket but i am getting this error

```
error Error [InternalError]: S3 aborted request
    at ./aws-reading/node_modules/@aws-sdk/middleware-sdk-s3/dist-cjs/throw-200-exceptions.js:16:21
```

functions to copycommand is below. s3Client is created successfully.

```
const updateMetaTag = async () => {
  const params = {
            Bucket: "mybucket",
            Key: 'key'
        };
        params.Metadata = { "time-taken": timeStamp }
    try
    {
        const command = new CopyObjectCommand(params);
        const response = await s3Client.send(command);
        console.log('response of updateMetaTag', response);
    } catch (error)
    {
        console.log('error', error);
    }
};
```

Comment: Don't you need a CopySource?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to copy the object from s3 to s3 using node.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46947288/how-to-copy-the-object-from-s3-to-s3-using-node-js)

Comment: thanks. it worked.  I was not able to find that in documentation