# node js code for copying file with metadata & its contents from s3 to s3 bucket

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda

I want to do below operations into lambda function

- In S3 bucket contains file with some content & metadata
- I want to copy same file & upload same location with epoc time

I written node js code in lambda function to take file, rename it & upload again

all things working fine but it uploading blank file.

used below code:

```
try {
      const listObjCom = new ListObjectsV2Command({
          Bucket: 'MY_BUCKET',
          Prefix: `/TEST`,
      });
      
      const listObjResponse = await s3.send(listObjCom);
    
      console.log("Bucket Contents---", JSON.stringify(listObjResponse));
      
      for await (const itm of listObjResponse.Contents){
        console.log("File name---"+itm.Key);
         if(itm.Key.includes("sample.json")){
            let spiltedFileName = itm.Key.split(".");
          
            console.log("spilted from filename1--->"+ spiltedFileName[0].toLowerCase());

            console.log("spilted from filename2--->"+ spiltedFileName[1].toLowerCase());
  
            //code to get epoc time
            Date.prototype.toUnixTime = function() { return this.getTime()/1000|0 };
            Date.time = function() { return new Date().toUnixTime(); }
    
            let epocTime =  Date.time();
      
            console.log("EPOC Time---"+epocTime);
            
            let newFileName = spiltedFileName[0].toLowerCase()+"_"+epocTime+"."+spiltedFileName[1].toLowerCase();
          
            console.log("File name after concate---"+newFileName);
          
            const bucketParams = {
              Bucket: 'MY_BUCKET',
              CopySource: '/test' + '/' + newFileName,
              Key: newFileName
            };
            
            const copyCommand = new CopyObjectCommand(bucketParams);
        
            const copyResponse = await s3.send(copyCommand);
            
            //const data = await s3.send(new PutObjectCommand(bucketParams));
            
            console.log(
              "Successfully uploaded File with New Name: " +
              bucketParams.Bucket +
              "/" +
              bucketParams.newFileName
            );
         }
      }
      
    }catch (error) {
      console.error("Error:" + event['custId'], error.message, error.stack);
    }
```

Above code uploads blank file with epoc time. no metadata were attached to new file. Can anyone tell me what is issue here?

Update:

Found solution for this. I used GetObjectCommand to get all content of file & passed those content in body of bucket params like

```
const bucketParams = {
          Bucket: event['bucket'],
          Body: JSON.stringify(rawData),
          Key: newFileName
        };
```

Comment: The object content seems to be not copied to S3 in your case. Copying object can be done with `copyObject()` function. Hope this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46947288/how-to-copy-the-object-from-s3-to-s3-using-node-js) helps with the solution.